# Why is there a \null in \verb?

Tags: verbatim, latex-base

In `source2e.pdf`, the definition of `\verb` is

```
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\@sverb\@verb}
```

There is a `\null` in non-mathematical model. `\null` is just `\hbox{}`. What is the purpose of using it here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a case, where `\null` makes a difference:

At the start of a line TeX removes glue and penalties. If `\verb` starts with an invisible space, then it would be removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent x\\
  \begingroup
    % \let\null\relax
    \verb| |y
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

`\null` as `\hbox{}` prevents that the space is gobbled at the start of a new line:

> [image: result without \null]

If `\null` is disabled, then the space is removed:

> [image: result with \null]

Thus `\null` helps that characters inside the argument of `\verb` do not vanish unexpectedly.

*Disclaimer:* I do not know the *real* reason, which the author of `\verb` had in mind.

Comment: Nice catch! You always surprise me.

Comment: This is the real reason. I kind of remember that this got added precisely for this way back